# Is there a limit on CNAME records for subdomains?

Tags: domain-name-system, cname-record

I've bought a domain, say `mydomain.com`. I'd like to set up google apps to work with it. As such, I'd like to create subdomains like `mail.mydomain.com`, `docs.mydomain.com`, etc. To integrate it with google, I must add to all of them CNAME records to `ghs.google.com`. However my domain registrar says that they can create only one CNAME in my domain, for which they chose `mail.mydomain.com`. The rest of them, they say, I must create as A type records.

Are they being lazy, or is there some limitation here that I'm not aware of?

Comment: It is the first time I hear a story like that.

Comment: @Irosa - For the record - it's not a `.com` domain, that was just for example. It's a local country domain. And yeah, if they keep this up I'll start checking whether there isn't another registrar I can use. This is somewhat ridiculous.

Comment: This is not a registrar issue, this is up to your DNS host. Change DNS host.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no such limitation with DNS.  There might be in some intermediate service they use.

Comment: They're the main registrar for the specific top level domain who maintain the zone. Other registrars go to them...

Comment: cnames are not set at the registrar.  They point to your dns nameservers, which can then have as many cnames as you want, as Oskar said.

Comment: In my case the company was all of it at once - TLD holder, registrar and DNS hoster.